# Не удается получить бесплатную подписку Azure

Tags: azure, account

При попытке получения бесплатной подписки / подписки по мере использования возникает ошибка.

1. Проверка личности с помощью телефона. На телефон приходит смс. В случае трёх попыток регистрации номер телефона блокируется (примерно на сутки). Возникает ошибка "Нет прав на создание подписки".
2. Проверка личности с помощью карты. Данные корректны. С карты списывалась (блокировалась) сумма в 30р. На данном этапе ошибок не возникало.
3. После подписания соглашения - "произошла непредвиденная ошибка, попробуйте позже". Соответственно, позже - тоже не работает.

В итоге аккаунт создался, но без подписки, т.е. использовать ничего не могу. 
В панели управления вижу "Каталог по умолчанию — ПРЕДВАРИТЕЛЬНАЯ ВЕРСИЯ".

Написал в техподдержку, но они не спешат помогать. Бесплатная поддержка работает с понедельника по пятницу с 10 до 18.

Есть предположение, что это из-за блокировки телеграмма. При попытке через регистрации через tor увидел дополнительное окошко (с просьбой указать дату рождения). Но при попытке создания подписки проблема та же.

Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобными проблемами? Как решали?

Comment: Ждите ответа от саппорта, обычно они отвечают в течении 8 часов.

Comment: Саппорт ответил, запросил дополнительную информацию обо мне. ( имя, название компании и др. ). Имя, кстати, указано в обращении, а вот где настроить компанию в которой я работаю и должность я не нашёл. На англоязычных форумах было указано, что это обязательное поле при регистрации

Comment: подписка в принципе создается с личного аккаунта (изначально), так что данные о компании вписывать некуда :)честно отвечайте как есть. они могут спрашивать данные для ручного создания подписки. если для себя - скажите, что фрилансер ИП и подписка нужна для себя.

Comment: мне не жалко ответить честно) я и ответил. В принципе, ожидаю ответа пытаться через tor)

Answer (score 1):

Итог:
Техподдержка ответила, что "учетная запись останется закрытой так как продолжает проявлять нерегулярную или подозрительную деятельность. " - видимо из-за того, что всё равно пытался периодически пытался получить доступ к подписке. И закрыла вопрос, не предоставляя сведений - можно ли вообще будет активировать аккаунт, и если можно, то когда. Получается "мёртвый аккаунт" без подписки, в котором ничего нельзя сделать - в том числе получить подписку.

Попытки зарегистрироваться через tor ни к чему не привели: просто не отображалась форма для заполнения данных карты.

Зарегистрировал новый email (на том же почтовике ), завёл новый аккаунт и без каких-либо проблем всё активировалось. То есть, видимо - был какой-то локальный сбой, после чего из-за продолжения попыток получения подписки поочередно блокировались "номер телефона" / "карта".